# Commands pasted into terminal are truncated

Tags: shell, terminal, copy-paste

I have a list of commands I would like to paste into the terminal so that they run one after the other.

Initially they run fine, but commands later on are being truncated.

Example command:

```
ogr2ogr -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI -progress -skipfailures -overwrite -lco PRECISION=no -f PostgreSQL PG:"dbname='natural_earth' host='localhost' port='5432' user='natural_earth' password='natural_earth'" 50m_physical/ne_50m_lakes.shp
```

There are about 150 of these commands, they are stored in gedit with line wrapping off and are being pasted as a block straight into the terminal.

Expected result:

```
$ ogr2ogr -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI -progress -skipfailures -overwrite -lco PRECISION=no -f PostgreSQL PG:"dbname='natural_earth' host='localhost' port='5432' user='natural_earth' password='natural_earth'" 50m_physical/ne_50m_lakes.shp
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

This works for about the first 30 commands, after which I get a varying level of truncation on the commands, for example:

```
$ ogr2o
ogr2o: command not found

$ ogr
ogr: command not found
```

```
$ ogr2ogr -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI -progress -skipfailures -overwrite -lco PRECISION=no -f PostgreSQL PG:"dbname='natural_earth' host='localhost' port='5432' user='natural_earth' password='natural_earth'" 50m_physical/ne_50m_graticules_all/ne_50m_grati

FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `50m_physical/ne_50m_graticules_all/ne_50m_grati'
```

So I am new to Linux. I was wondering if there was a better way to run these than copy & paste from gedit?

I am running Linux Mint 15 "olivia" Cinnamon 32-bit.

Comment: Presuming there's nothing else in the gedit buffer, save it as a file and run it through the shell via `sh [filename]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put the commands you want to run in a special file, and execute it as a shell script. Either by invoking a shell with an argument:

```
sh your_commands
```

or by prepending the commands with a [hashbang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_bang) and marking the file as executable with `chmod a+x your_commands`:

```
#!/bin/sh
your commands
go
here
```

which will make it behave as a regular binary and you will be able to just execute

```
 /path/to/your_commands
```

Alternatively you can also use the `source` functionality of your shell, which executes the commands from a file inside of the current shell (as opposed to spwaning a new shell which is what the two above will do):

```
source your_commands
```

or

```
. your_commands
```

(both have the same meaning).

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to Stack Exchange, and also to Linux Mint!

You ask whether there is a better way than paste-into-terminal to run a long series of commands. As it happens, there is: save the commands into a file, and run it as a shell script.

E.g. if you save your commands in `~/scripts/myscript.sh` (`~` is the abbreviation for your home directory), you can run it by entering these commands:

```
# change directory to where the script is
cd ~/scripts
# run the script with bash (most scripts are bash scripts)
bash myscript.sh
```

#### Pay attention to your working directory

One thing to look out for: the directory from where you run `bash myscript.sh` will be used as the working directory. If your script talks about the file `50m_physical/lakes.sh`, which is in your `~/mylakesproject` directory, then this will work:

```
cd mylakesproject
bash ~/scripts/myscript.sh
# ~/mylakesproject/50m_physical/lakes.sh exists
```

and this will not work:

```
cd myotherproject
bash ~/scripts/myscript.sh
# ~/myotherproject/50m_physical/lakes.sh does not exist
```

and neither will this:

```
cd scripts
bash myscript.sh
# ~/scripts/50m_physical/lakes.sh does not exist
```

Good luck, and have fun!